# How to fix my ASP.NET controller not sending child class data?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have an abstract class `MyAbsData` with two classes `MyExtraData` and `MySpecialData` inheriting from it.

I have a container class `DataContainer` which includes a list of the abstract class type.

When sending the container through a controller endpoint the list data is 'cut' into the data that the `MyAbsData` contain

```
[ApiController]
[Route("container")]
public class TestingController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("")]
    public DataContainer GetContainer()
    {
        var container = new DataContainer();
        container.AddData(new MySpecialData(0));
        container.AddData(new MySpecialData(1));
        container.AddData(new MyExtraData(2, 3));
        container.AddData(new MyExtraData(4, 5));
        container.AddData(new MyExtraData(6, 7));
        container.AddData(new MySpecialData(8));

        return container;
    }
}

public class DataContainer
{
    public List<MyAbsData> MyList { get; }

    public DataContainer()
    {
        MyList = new List<MyAbsData>();
    }

    public void AddData(MyAbsData data)
    {
        MyList.Add(data);
    }
}

public abstract class MyAbsData
{
    public int Data1 { get; }

    public MyAbsData(int data1)
    {
        Data1 = data1;
    }
}

public class MySpecialData : MyAbsData
{
    public MySpecialData(int data1) : base(data1) { }
}

public class MyExtraData : MyAbsData
{
    public int Data2 { get; }

    public MyExtraData(int data1, int data2) : base(data1)
    {
        Data2 = data2;
    }
}
```

Checking the API, I get

```
{
    "myList": [
        {
            "data1": 0
        },
        {
            "data1": 1
        },
        {
            "data1": 2
        },
        {
            "data1": 4
        },
        {
            "data1": 6
        },
        {
            "data1": 8
        }
    ]
}
```

I expected to have the data2 values included in the list.

I tried using Json attributes and to play with the structure of the data but nothing really helped with getting the data2 values into the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you provided, since the DataContainer saves a list of type MyAbsData, when you add an instance of MyExtraData to the container, the list will only display the properties and methods defined in MyAbsData. So the values of Data2 cannot be seen because they are not part of the MyAbsData class.If you want to include the value of Data2 in the list, you can change the type of the list in the DataContainer class so that it holds an instance of MyExtraData instead of MyAbsData. This way, each element in the list will be of type MyExtraData, allowing direct access to the Data2 value.Here is an example you can use as a reference:

```
[ApiController]
    [Route("Next")]
    public class NextController : Controller
    {

        [HttpGet("")]
        public DataContainer GetContainer()
        {
            var container = new DataContainer();
            container.AddData(new MySpecialData(0));
            container.AddData(new MySpecialData(1));
            container.AddData(new MyExtraData(2, 3));
            container.AddData(new MyExtraData(4, 5));
            container.AddData(new MyExtraData(6, 7));
            container.AddData(new MySpecialData(8));

            return container;
        }
    }

        public class DataContainer
        {
            public List<MyExtraData> MyList { get; }

            public DataContainer()
            {
                MyList = new List<MyExtraData>();
            }

            public void AddData(MyExtraData data)
            {
                MyList.Add(data);
            }
        }

        public abstract class MyAbsData
        {
            public int Data1 { get; }

            public MyAbsData(int data1)
            {
                Data1 = data1;
            }
        }

        public class MySpecialData : MyAbsData
        {
            public MySpecialData(int data1) : base(data1) { }
        }

        public class MyExtraData : MyAbsData
        {
            public int Data2 { get; }

            public MyExtraData(int data1, int data2) : base(data1)
            {
                Data2 = data2;
            }
        }
```

My result list:

[image]

You can also achieve this by changing the list type to List by setting it. Since MySpecialData and MyExtraData are both subclasses of object, they can be added to List, but due to the need for type checking at runtime or Conversion will increase code redundancy when the structure is complex, so it is mostly used to understand this example rather than actual use:

```
public class DataContainer
{
    public List<object> MyList { get; }

    public DataContainer()
    {
        MyList = new List<object>();
    }

    public void AddData(MyAbsData data)
    {
        MyList.Add(data);
    }
}
```

**Updated**

```
 [ApiController]
[Route("Next")]
public class NextController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("")]
    public ActionResult<DataContainer> GetContainer()
    {
        var container = new DataContainer();
        container.AddData(new MySpecialData(0));
        container.AddData(new MySpecialData(1));
        container.AddData(new MyExtraData(2, 3));
        container.AddData(new MyExtraData(4, 5));
        container.AddData(new MyExtraData(6, 7));
        container.AddData(new MySpecialData(8));

        var checkList = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

        foreach (var item in container.MyList)
        {
            checkList.Add(item.GetData());
        }

        var result = new { myList = checkList };
        return Json(result);
    }
}

public class DataContainer
{
    public List<MyAbsData> MyList { get; }

    public DataContainer()
    {
        MyList = new List<MyAbsData>();
    }

    public void AddData(MyAbsData data)
    {
        MyList.Add(data);
    }
}

public abstract class MyAbsData
{
    public int Data1 { get; }

    public MyAbsData(int data1)
    {
        Data1 = data1;
    }

    public abstract Dictionary<string, object> GetData();
}

public class MySpecialData : MyAbsData
{
    public MySpecialData(int data1) : base(data1) { }

    public override Dictionary<string, object> GetData()
    {
        return new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "data1", Data1 }
    };
    }
}

public class MyExtraData : MyAbsData
{
    public int Data2 { get; }

    public MyExtraData(int data1, int data2) : base(data1)
    {
        Data2 = data2;
    }

    public override Dictionary<string, object> GetData()
    {
        return new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "data1", Data1 },
        { "data2", Data2 }
    };
    }
}
```

Result list:

[image]

Comment: The second method works, but I want to use a base class as a type instead of the object type.

The first method throws a conversion error when calling the AddData method with the `MySpecialData` objects as they are not of type `MyExtraData`.

If there are no other solutions to this issue I will use the second method as it does.

Comment: You can add a method to your derived class that returns a dictionary that represents information about the object. Then call this method in a loop and build a JSON structure to implement it.I updated my code you can refer to the example.